# Cannot access Apache server from Android phone

Tags: android, apache, wamp

I have a WAMP server running on my Windows 7 PC. I wish to access it from my Android phone's browser.
Example: A HTML page on my server (`localhost/example.html`) should be accessible on the Android phone's web browser (`192.168.1.xx/example.html`)

1. Both the devices are in the same range of IPs `192.168.1.xx`
2. The `httpd.conf` for my Apache contains `Listen 80`
3. It is accessible from other PCs on the same network (Home LAN)
4. Windows Firewall is turned off.

EDIT : Whoa! it works from my office WLAN. Can anyone explain what might be the reason for that?

Comment: Did you try hosting anything else(not in apache server) and access it from the phone???, this will tell if the problem is connectivity or server configuration.Besides remember antivirus sets a firewall too.

Comment: Did you tried accessing like this `http://10.0.2.2/example.html` ??

Comment: windows firewall is off that is ok but do you have any firewall configured on your router? Have you looked at apache's error/access logs?

Comment: @VishalVyas, He is actually refering to the phone and not the emulator,if that where the case then your comment would be useful.

Comment: @Daniel Tried with my antivirus firewall off as well, no luck.


It works fine in Opera Emulator. Does that mean it is not an apache issue, but a connectivity problem?

Comment: @VishalVyas Yes, that doesn't work.

Comment: Give acces Everyone to your virtual directory's physical folder...

Comment: Did you set a custom proxy in the browser that is not working???.That could be messing things up.

Comment: Ohhh sorry about that.. check if this helps..
http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/ ;)

Comment: I'm not an expert on Apache servers but in IIS you can set your website to be accesible from all IPs by changing the correct IIS config file, I think you should do the same with Apache.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I have already done the needful in the config file.
No, I have not set custom proxy settings. Also, can you suggest me a lightweight server wby which I can test your first comment.

Comment: Try hosting a simple website(with only Default.aspx) in .Net, this is easy as hell if you have VisualStudio installed.:)

Comment: @VishalVyas That is exactly what I am looking for, but sadly, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using IIS on my windows 7 and I am calling a page from my Android phone succesfuly. Url is like this:

http://192.168.1.xx/example.html

I lived in the same issue and I turned off any firewall on my windows 7 and I gave acces Everyone to my virtual directory's physical folder now it is ok...

Comment: Please elaborate "I gave acces Everyone to my virtual directory's physical folder".

Comment: Right-click the folder that contains your example.html file. And go to security tab. And give acces to eveyone.

Comment: you said "It is accessible from other PCs on the same network (Home LAN) " so the problem with your wirelles network or you phone!!!

Comment: I meant WLAN, the other PCs are on the same wireless network as the phone.

Comment: Restart your pc, restart apache server and restart your phone.